# Splitting GeoPandas DataFrame evenly by distance

Tags: geopandas

Is it possible to split a GeoPandas DataFrame that contains LineStrings in evenly spaced segments?

I have a DataFrame loaded from a shapefile that contains the track of a railway. I want to project data on the track in a 100m resolution, but the LineStrings (per row in the DataFrame) from the original data are ugly spaced. So I want to "spatially resample".

I guess I have to start with union to make a MultiLine object with all LineStrings. And then split down along the track.

Comment: I think your guess is a good way forward. Once you have one big merged LineString, you could use `interpolate` (https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.interpolate) to create points along that LineString at certain distances, and then you can use those points to split the line or to create new line segments.